# New RAM making computer restarts immediately

Tags: memory

i have some sort of issue with RAM.

I just bought 2x 4 GB Kingston (Part no. **KVR16N11S8/4**) and i put them in blue slots (Mainboard: **Asus P7H55-M SI**) but when i turn on the computer, it restarts in 2 seconds, just after the ASUS logo.

I cannot even enter BIOS.

However, when i put only one, i can enter BIOS, but cannot boot into Windows (10), it restarts when logo shows up.

Tried to lower frequency to 1333, 1066, 800 Mhz, nothing works. My mainboard doesn't have voltage settings in BIOS (upgraded BIOS to latest version).

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This sounds like a compatibility issue. Are you sure you are using the correct memory? Have you read the important details about memory for your board at the [ASUS site](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P7H55M/specifications/)?

Comment: You may also want to take a look at the [Memory/Device Support](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P7H55M/HelpDesk_QVL/) documents for your board. These are very specific depending on the processor you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There should be voltage options in BIOS to enter in manually as shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JFr-GUzGdc

Whenever DRAM frequency is changed, Latency and voltages has to be raised/lowered depending on the frequency.

But that being said, 1600 MHz memory is supported with clocking, even up to 2133 MHz of DDR3. So, it is a memory issue, try the memory in 3rd and 4th slots, or either 3rd or 4th for individual testing, see if that makes any changes.

Before attempting this, change BIOS settings to default and try.